# Specifying specific days in WinServer task scheduler:

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a task to run on a Win Server 2008 R2 machine. I set up it to run from the windows task scheduler that comes with Windows. I need to run the task DAILY but NOT on weekends.

I did not find any place in the task scheduler giving me that option: Under Triggers for a task, there are options for One Time, Daily, Weekly, and Monthly - no place to set a task to run on particular days only or to skip weekends.

How can I do this? (without setting up 5 separate weekly tasks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select "Weekly" then select each day of the week that you want the task to run every week. So, in your case you would select Monday through Friday, being sure to set the "Recur every x weeks" to 1.